# Sort "Done" Jira Agile column

Tags: jira

We are using Jira Agile and we have a board with columns:

```
Ideas
Next Up
On Hold
In Progress
Done
```

Cards can be moved from left to right with the goal of moving the card to done. Right now when I move the card to done it basically places it at the bottom of the done column. I would like it to sort descending so the most recent "done" issue is placed at the top of this column.

Here's a screen shot of what I want to sort:

[image]

When someone completes an issue they drag and drop to done, but the issue is it goes to the bottom of this column.  I want it to go to the top so we have a descending order.  I don't see a setup to change the sort order on one column, but if it is there and I don't see it please let me know!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each board has a filter, the filter contains the order. By default this is rank, because you pick lower ranked tasks later they get dropped at the bottom of the done column.

You are looking to update your filter to something like:

```
project = TST ORDER BY resolutiondate DESC, rank ASC
```

This way if the issue is finish it gets ordered on its resolution date, if its not yet finished it will be ordered by backlog ranking.

You can edit and find the filter under Board(top right)->Configure->General->Filter->Edit Filter Query

Actually this makes perfect sense, I think I will update my own boards to use this aswell.

Comment: You know what's funny I looked at that field time after time and I thought that cannot be it...This is exactly what I needed, and I am glad you will be updating your boards as well..It makes it all the better!  Thanks

Comment: I set it up, but ran into an issue when ranking in the backlog screen: Ranking is disabled, as the Filter Query for this board is not ordered by ascending Rank. Please check your filter configuration.

Comment: I want to try this, too, but your last comment made me to stop. Could you solve this disabled "Ranking" filter problem.

Comment: I'm not having any issues with this.  Not sure why though, it works for me.